# SAILS: How to define association table mysql many-many

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

As I have read in the documentation "Waterline will look at your models and if it finds that two models both have collection attributes that point to each other, it will automatically build up a join table for you." My question is how will waterline know which table is the association table as I am getting an error right now

> unknow column `NaN` in where clause

I am using MYSQL as a db and my models looks like this:

Sells.js:

```
module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: true,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    createdAt:{
        type:'datetime',
        columnName:'created'
    },
    qty_sold:{
        type:'float'
    },
    s_notes:{
        type:'string'
    },
    items: {
      collection: 'species',
      via: 'sales',
      dominant:true
    }
  }
};
```

Species.js:

```
    module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    name:{
        type:'string',      
    },
    qty:{
        type:'float',   
    },
    sort:{
        type:'float',
    },
    quickbooks_listid:{
        type:'string'   
    },
    quickbooks_editsequence:{
        type:'string'   
    },
    isEdited:{
        type:'integer'
    },
    cut_fish:{
        type:'integer'
    },
    // Add a reference to Sells
    sales: {
      collection: 'sells',
      via: 'items',
      //dominant: true
    }
  }
```

};

And I have 2 existing tables in mysql DB:
species and sells

Answer (score 0):

Sell:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},

species:{
  collection: "species", // match model name here
  via: "Sells", // match attribute name on other model
  dominant: true // dominant side
}
```

Species.js:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},

sells:{
  collection: "Sells", // match model name
  via: "Species" // match attribute name
}
```